# How to allow each subplot in hvplot to have it's own x-axis scaling?

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot

I have a data frame that has three columns: `stage` (which has two values, `"before"` and `"after"`, which stands for "before and after preprocessing"), `variable` (holding the name for each variable) and `value` (holding the values for each variable for different subjects). I would like to plot the histogram of values for each variable separately for each stage (`"before"` and `"after"`). I came up with the following solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import hvplot
from holoviews import opts

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stage':['before','before','before','before','after','after','after','after'],
     'variable':['foo','foo','bar','bar','foo','foo','bar','bar'],
     'value':[1,1,2,2,1,1,30,30]})

# Create separate histograms for the "before" and "after" groups
histograms_before = df[df['stage'] == 'before'].hvplot.hist(y='value',by='variable',subplots=True)
histograms_after = df[df['stage'] == 'after'].hvplot.hist(y='value',by='variable',subplots=True)

# Combine the "before" and "after" histograms into a single plot with two columns
histograms = histograms_before.cols(1) + histograms_after.cols(1)

# Display the histograms with a scrollbar
histograms.opts(opts.Layout(shared_axes=False)).cols(2)
hvplot.show(histograms)
```

which gives you the following facet plot:

[image]

This however forces all x-axes in each column to have the same x-axis scaling. For example, the variable `foo` has the same values for `"before"` and `"after"` so I would want the x-axis scaling to be the same for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Libraries like altair allow you to do this by setting the axis dimensions to be independent.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this library. Would you mind sharing a code example? :)